# PHP : Calling classes - Whats the diference?

Tags: php, function, class, oop, call

What's the difference between this two types of methods of calling functions within classes:

**Method One:**

```
Myclass::returnValue('the value');
```

**Method Two:**

```
$returnthevalue = new MyClass();
$returnthevalue->returnValue('the value');
```

(Both of them print the same)

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function returnValue($string){
        echo "<br><strong>";
        echo 'This is the value: ' . $string;
        echo "<br></strong>";
    }

}

Myclass::returnValue('some');
$returnthevalue = new MyClass();
$returnthevalue->returnValue('the value');
```

Comment: Your first call is a static method call.  And you should not call that way unless it's correctly labelled static.

Comment: Your method name `returnValue` is also misleading.  Because your method does not return anything (or rather returns null).